# Multiple requests asynchronously with same callback function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-async, node-request

```
 var parsedUrl = req.body.parsedUrl;
  console.log(parsedUrl);
  var options = {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + parsedUrl,
      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'request'
      }
  };

   var options2 = {
       url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + parsedUrl + '/readme',
       headers: {
           'User-Agent': 'request'
       }
   };

 function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var info = JSON.parse(body);
          Thing.create(info, function(err, thing) {
            //console.log(info);
            if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            return res.json(201, thing);
          });

      } else {
        console.log('github request error');
      }

  }
  request(options, callback);
  request(options2, callback);
```

Basically, i need to make two requests so my questions are the following : 
1. How can i make those two requests asynchronously using async module. I have tried to use async.parallel however the syntax doesn't play well with request's syntax since async.parallel takes a callback.

2.How can i sort of merge the results ? I need to save them to the database at the same time in the same object in Mongo.

I hope this makes sense. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `async` library:

```
npm install async --save
```

Create an array with `options` and `options2` and call `request` on each item in the array:

```
async.map([options, options2], request, function(err, results) {
  // results[0] is the response for options
  // results[1] is the response for options2
  // you can merge them here and insert into mongodb as one document
});
```